# extjs 4 desktop start menu entries behind taskbar

Tags: extjs4, desktop, startmenu

The startmenu contains several entries
and sub entries.

Like in any other start menu
the entries appear top-->down.

But now i can't click the last entry
because it vanishes behind taskbar.

```
|-- sub1
|    |-- entry1_1
|    |-- sub2 
|         |-- sub3
|         |    |-- entry3_1
|         |    |-- entry3_2
start menu     |-- entry3_3   <--- not visible / behind taskbar
```

Any idea how to "auto-adapt" the height of start menu
in extjs 4 desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought this would be automatically handled by the zIndexManager, but you could try manually setting the zIndex. Maybe try 100 for sub1, 200 for sub2 300 for sub3 etc..

```
style: {
   zIndex:100
}
```